# Assigning latitude and longitude in MVCarray

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arrays, database

Im trying to fetch my mysql data I've read some article in 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-heatmap

```
    <?php
    $locations = mysql_query("select * from locations");        
?>
<?php                           
    $lats = "";         // string with latitude values
    $lngs = ""; 

    while ($locat = mysql_fetch_array($locations))
    {
    $lats = $locat['latitude'];
    $lngs = $locat['longitude'];
    $taxiData = [new google.maps.LatLng($lats,$lngs)];
    }
?>
```

instead of `var taxiData = [new google.maps.LatLng(37.782551, -122.445368)];`

now Im trying to fetch the value in those latitude and longitude.

Comment: What is your question? What is happening, and how is it not what you expect?

Comment: $taxiData = [new google.maps.LatLng($lats,$lngs)]; <- I wanted to make sure if this is the correct thing to do. to replicate this var taxiData = [new google.maps.LatLng(37.782551, -122.445368)];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to execute the js example in PHP. Really, U'll need to learn a bit about web development, but You can try something like  this trying to make it working right now:

```
<?php /* You should add all needed external js scripts above  */?>
<script type="text/javascript"> 

//Here You should put everything before the points array declaring from the example   
<?php 
    $locations = mysql_query("select * from locations");

    echo 'var taxiData = [';        
    while ($locat = mysql_fetch_array($locations))
        echo "new google.maps.LatLng({$locat['latitude']}, {$locat['longitude']}),\n";
    echo '];';
//Here You should put everything after the points array declaring from the example  
?>
</script>
```

The code above is terrible, but the js part will be sent to the browser and the browser will try to execute it. Anyway, U should take a read a little about web development, otherwise a lot of simple things will be hard enough for You. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be mixing `php` and javascript with abandon. If you want to issue a javascript command, you have to make sure it looks like javascript to the browser.  Maybe something like

```
<?php
    $locations = mysql_query("select * from locations");        
?>

<?php                           
    $lats = "";         // string with latitude values
    $lngs = ""; 

    while ($locat = mysql_fetch_array($locations))
    {
    $lats = $locat['latitude'];
    $lngs = $locat['longitude'];
    $taxiString = "new google.maps.LatLng($lats,$lngs)";
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var taxiData = [<?=$taxiString?>];
    // do whatever you want in javascript
</script>
    }
?>
```

A tested snippet that demonstrates the idea (I could not test the above easily):

```
<html>
<?php
 for($i=0;$i<2;$i++) {
   $myString = "It works $i times!";
   echo $myString;
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
alert("<?= $myString; ?>");
</script>
<?php
}
?>
</html>
```

When you run that you will see that the `php` string `$myString` was properly inserted into the JavaScript.

Let me clarify a little bit more.

Javascript is code that is executed by the BROWSER. php is code that is executed on the SERVER. The BROWSER will be asking Google Maps for some information - it is your task to make sure that the command that the browser issues is correct. php is nice in that it allows you to change the text that appears in the browser.

The way to understand the difference is to look at the source code of a web page in your browser. The second snippet I posted above is actually available on http://www.floris.us/SO/mix.php

When you open it in your browser, and you look at the source code, you will see

```
<html>
It works 0 times!<script type="text/javascript">
alert("It works 0 times!");
</script>
It works 1 times!<script type="text/javascript">
alert("It works 1 times!");
</script>
</html>
```

Breaking it down a little bit ( and adding some carriage returns for clarity):

```
<html>              - this was text in my original file
It works 0 times!   - this was the result of a php echo command
<script type="text/javascript"> - literal text in original file
alert("             - literal text
It works 0 times!   - the result of <?= $myString; ?>
");                 - literal text
</script>           - literal text
```

And then something crazy - the same thing repeats (because of the php loop) - BUT WITH A DIFFERENT VALUE (1 instead of 0):

```
It works 1 times!<script type="text/javascript">
alert("It works 1 times!");
</script>

</html>             - this last line did not repeat because it's outside the php loop
```

Final comment:

```
<?= $myString; ?>
```

is shorthand for

```
<?php echo $myString; ?>
```